# Add a char to the links in table of contents

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, char, addition, tableofcontents

I found this script that exactly meets my requirements. I would now like to add a >> char to the link.

It should not just be a list symbol before the link, it should be a part of the link. Can someone give me a tip on how I can do this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {                                                                          
    $(tocSide).empty();                                                            

    var prevH2Item = null;                                                            
    var prevH2List = null;                                                            

    var index = 0;                                                                    
    $("h2").each(function() {                                                     

        //insert an anchor to jump to, from the TOC link.            
        var anchor = "<a name='" + index + "'></a>";                 
        $(this).before(anchor);                                     

        var li = "<li><a href='#" + index + "'>" + $(this).text() + "</a></li>"; 

            if( $(this).is("h2") ){                                     
            prevH2List = $("<ul></ul>");                
            prevH2Item = $(li);                                     
            prevH2Item.append(prevH2List);                          
            prevH2Item.appendTo("#tocSide");                        
        } else {                                                    
            prevH2List.append(li);                                  
        }                                 
        index++;                                                    
    });                                                             

});
```

Comment: which variable is storing your "link" ?

Comment: I think its var li but all tries to add a String are failed

Comment: Why don't you debug your code to see which variable holds which value? We cannot help if even you didn't know how your code works... But looking to it right now, I would give a shot in the dark that you need something like: `<a href='#>>" + index + ...`